# Can't get to forward ports with Iptables

Tags: networking, server, iptables

In my "router" machine I have the following `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo eth0 eth1 eth2 eth3
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# Subred 1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.10.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0

# Subred 2 (dhcp)
iface eth2 inet static
    address 192.168.20.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0

# Host-only
iface eth3 inet static
    address 192.168.56.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.56.255
```

In `~/.bashrc` (at least for now, later could be in `/etc/network/interfaces`) :

```
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.20:80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.20.46:22
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -d 192.168.10.20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -d 192.168.30.50 -j ACCEPT
```

And `iptables -t nat-L` gives me:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http to:192.168.10.20:80
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh to:192.168.20.46:22
```

And yet I can connect neither to the web server in `192.168.10.20` nor to the ssh server in `192.168.30.50` from outside the subnet. From the inside there's no problem.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying all this time to connect via `eth3` and hadn't redirected traffic from it, only from `eth0`. A stupid mistake that took days to solve...